# how to pass array to inner html in polymer

Tags: javascript, polymer

I am totally new to polymer.I want to draw a graph...

I have one html where I include attributes like this... for the dom module

```
<some-container content_content-type = 'Real Estate' content_content-num = 'PF HP 001078' key-type = 'vpn_key' graphmax = 620000 graphmin = 540000 currency = 'USD' oldvalue-amount = 550000 new-value-amount = 2300 new-valuecolor = 'green-text' new-valueplusminus = '+' morelink = '#' containerlink = 'education.html' graphdata = [['Tue', 600000],['Wed', 590000],['Thu', 580000],['Fri', 575000],['Sat', 590000],['Sun', 575000],['Mon', 550000],['Tue', null]]></some-container>
```

Now I want to send this array graphdata as parameter… as I sent the others like… content_content-type, content_content-num, etc.

```
<dom-module id="some-container">
  <template>
….HTML…
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({        
           is: 'some-container',
           properties: {
                                content_contentType: {
                                                type:     String,
                                                notify: true
                                },
                                content_contentNum: {
                                                type:     String,
                                                notify: true
                                }, 
….
                                graphdata: {
                                                type: Array,
                                                value: []
                                },
….
};
                attached: function() {
                                                this._drawgraph(this.graphmax,this.graphmin,this.graphid,this.graphdata); //  _drawgraph is some other function where functionality/calculations are…
                                //If I debug I see this.graphmax, this.graphmin has data… but not this.graphdata
                                },
```

But I see that this.graphdata is not getting data. Its undefined.

Any suggestion how do I pass the array from the external HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass quoted [JSON|Array] to element property directly in HTML you must invert the quotes. The attribute value must be surrounded by single quotes and the actual string must use double quotes. Otherwise Polymer fails to parse it, because single quotes are not correct JSON syntax. Thus your code should be

```
<some-container graphdata='[["Tue", 600000],["Wed", 590000],["Thu", 580000],["Fri", 575000],["Sat", 590000],["Sun", 575000],["Mon", 550000],["Tue", null]]'></some-container>
```

Comment: For reference, here's where it's mentioned in the documentation: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties#configuring-object-and-array-properties

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that the way it is parsed it is treated as JSON by Polymer, so you have to always use single quotes for array attributes, and double quotes inside the array.

Here's a working example, it seems a little slow to run on StackOverflow, but it should work after some few seconds.

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>Testing App</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="http://polygit.org/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="http://polygit.org/polymer+:master/components/polymer/polymer.html">
  </head>
  <body>

    <dom-module id="example-element">
      <template>
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[_processArray(graphdata)]]">
          <p>[[item.key]]: [[item.value]]</p>
        </template>
      </template>
      <script>
        Polymer({
          is: 'example-element',

          properties: {

            graphdata: {
              type: Array
            }
          },

          _processArray(arr) {
            var processed = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
              processed.push({
                key: arr[i][0],
                value: arr[i][1]
              });
            }
            return processed;
          }
        });
      </script>
    </dom-module>
        
    <example-element graphdata='[["Tue", 600000],["Wed", 590000],["Thu", 580000],["Fri", 575000],["Sat", 590000],["Sun", 575000],["Mon", 550000],["Tue", null]]'></example-element>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thnaks for the reply,
But I tried like that ... still this.graphdata is coming as null.. so the graph is not painting

Comment: I have updated the answer and added a working example.